# this.props is undefined inside Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**Problem**: When I try passing panels to my createTabs() inside create tabs props `this.props` is `undefined` **inside createTabs()**.  When I put a breakpoint on panels at the line `const tabs = this.createTabs(panels);`, `panels` has a value, so I know that's fine.

I also want feedback on where I'm trying to initialize my tabs (that call) is in the right lifecycle method.

Here is a screencast to help show you the issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z04LV8LHCvI

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
...

export default class Tabs extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    ....

    };

    this.state = {
      ...
      tabs: null,
    };

    this.createTabs = this.createTabs.bind(this);
    ...
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { panels } = this.props;
    const panel = _.get(panels, 'member.0');

    if (panel) {
      this.tabChanged(0, _.get(panel, 'headline'));
      const filters = shapeFilters(_.get(panel, 'customViews'), this.setSelectedFilter);
      this.setState({ selectedFilter: (filters && filters.length > 0) ? filters[0] : null });
    }

    const tabs = this.createTabs(panels);
    this.setState({ tabs });
  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    const { selectedTab: currentTab, panels: currentPanels } = this.props;
    ....

    if (currentTab === nextTab) return null;

    const { panels } = this.props;
    const filter = { selectedFilter: null };
    const nextFilterName = _.get(nextFilter, 'name', null);

    if (panels && nextFilter) {
      ...
    }
    ...
    this.setState({ filter });
  }


  createTabs() {
    // this.props is undefined, why?????
    const tabs = this.props.panels.member.map((panel, idx) => {
      const { selectedTab } = this.props;
      const { id: panelId, headline } = panel;
      const url = getHeaderLogo(panel, 50);
      const item = url ? <img src={url} alt={headline} /> : headline;

      const classname = classNames([
        searchResultsTheme.tabItem,
        (idx === selectedTab) ? searchResultsTheme.active : null,
      ]);

      this.setFilter(panel, idx, selectedTab);

      return (
        <TabItem
          key={panelId}
          classname={`${classname} search-tab`}
          headline={headline}
          idx={idx}
          content={item}
          onclick={this.tabChanged}
        />
      );
    });

    return tabs;
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className={searchResultsTheme.filters}>
        <ul className={`${searchResultsTheme.tabs} search-tabs`}>{this.state.tabs}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SearchTabs.defaultProps = {
  panels: {},
  ...
};

SearchTabs.propTypes = {
  panels: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
.....
};

export const TabItem = ({ classname, content, onclick, key }) => (
  <li key={key} className={`${classname} tab-item`} onClick={onclick} >{content}</li>
);
```

Comment: You need to pass props into the constructor and the call to super.

Comment: thanks I'll try that out.  I guess I'm so used to connected containers.

Comment: `this.createTabs = this.createTabs.bind(this);` is only necessary if you pass the function as event handler somewhere, which you are not doing.

Comment: thank you @FelixKing, good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props will not be available inside your class unless you pass them explicitly into the constructor and when invoking super.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ....

    };

    this.state = {
      ...
      tabs: null,
    };

    this.createTabs = this.createTabs.bind(this);
    ...
  }
```